# Clojure to Scala translation: L System update

Tags: scala, clojure

I'm attempting to model an L-system for a class project, but I'm struggling with Scala's reduce/fold and typesystem for achieving this end after many months of Clojure.

In Clojure, I would write

```
user> (defn update-state [translation-map, state]
          (mapcat #(get translation-map %1 [%1]) state))
user> (def translations {"a" ["b", "a", "b"]})
user> (update-state translations ["a"])
["b", "a", "b"]
```

This trick works because I implicitly defined `(update-state "b") => ["b"]`, and I use `clojure.core/mapcat` to take care of `concat`ing the translated values together.

So if we apply this operation twice, we see that the example L-system is behaving as intended..

```
user> (->> ["a"] 
           (update-state translations)
           (update-state translations))
["b", "b", "a", "b", "b"]
```

my Scala attempt thereat is

```
package me.arrdem.planter;
import scala.collection.mutable.{HashMap,LinkedList};

class LSystem[keytype,fntype] {
  var _invoke_map = HashMap[keytype,fntype]()
  var _tr_map = HashMap[keytype,Seq[keytype]]()

  def translate(s:Seq[keytype], k:keytype) : Seq[keytype] = {
    s ++ (if(_tr_map contains(k)) _tr_map.get(k) else (k))
  }

  def step(s:Seq[keytype]) : Seq[keytype] = {
    s foldRight(LinkedList[keytype]())(translate)
  }
}
```

Which should, it seems to me, work save that the typechecker complains

```
ERROR: type mismatch;  found   : Seq[Any]  required: Seq[keytype] : line 9
ERROR: type mismatch;  found   : keytype  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?] : line 9
ERROR: type mismatch;  found   : keytype  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?] : line 9
```

Now when I read this, the implied error is that somehow the expression `(if(_tr_map contains(k)) _tr_map.get(k) else (k))` is type-inferred to be `Seq[Any]` rather than `Seq[keytype]`.

As the two outcomes are 1) key found -> `Seq[keytype]` and 2) key not found -> singleton tuple `(k)`, how is this possible and how can I correct it?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
s ++ (if(_tr_map contains(k)) _tr_map.get(k) else (k))
```

With:

```
s ++ _tr_map.get(k).getOrElse(Seq[keytype](k))
```

Your problem is that `HashMap.get(k)` returns an `Option` and that `k` is a `keytype`, not a `Seq[keytype]` expected by the `++` operator.

Now for your second problem, you can't `foldRight` with your translate function unless you change the order of the arguments.

You can either `foldLeft` and `reverse`:

```
  def step(s: Seq[keytype]): Seq[keytype] = {
    s.foldLeft(Seq[keytype]())(translate)
  }
```

Or change your `translate` function to:

```
 def translate(k:keytype, s:Seq[keytype]) : Seq[keytype] = {
     s ++ _tr_map.get(k).getOrElse(Seq[keytype](k))
 }
```

And then you can `foldRight`:

```
def step(s: Seq[keytype]): Seq[keytype] = {
  s.foldRight(Seq[keytype]())(translate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Seq needs to be 'right' parameter : (foldRight means accumulator is right)
def translate(k: keytype, s:Seq[keytype]) : Seq[keytype] = {
    s ++ (if(_tr_map contains(k)) _tr_map.get(k).get else Seq(k))

                             // Hashmap.get returns an option so you need another get
                             // in else condition you need Seq(k)
}

def step(s:Seq[keytype]) : Seq[keytype] = {

   s.foldRight(Seq[keytype]())(translate)

   // need dotted syntax for foldRight
   // or (s foldRight Seq[keytype]()) (translate)
}
```